# Gradient text with GD library from PHP

Tags: php, gd, gradient

With this function, we can create gradient image : http://planetozh.com/blog/my-projects/images-php-gd-gradient-fill/

I need to create gradient text, or put a gradient over a black image. (Must have transparent background)

It's kind of easy within Photoshop, but I don't know all functions of GD library so maybe there is a way to get that.

Who wanna try? ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think I find something... Tell me what you thing

Supose that I have a transparent image with a black circle inside. I want to make the circle transparent o i can put an image behind.

1. Open the image (Duh!)
2. Replace the transparency with 255, 35, 255 (Pink)
3. Replace the black with transparency
4. Create new image + generate gradient
5. Merge the first image with the gradient image
6. Make the pink transparent! :)

Is that make sense?